# Is there a way to mimic format painter in Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing a C# program to manipulate a couple of Excel files (xls format) using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. What I need to do is to add a new sheet and write some data, whose format is similar as the data in some existing sheets. So basically I would like to find a way to perform the action like `format painter` when we modify Excel file manually. What I mean is, I need to set the number format, the background color, font, font color, alignment, and so on.

I tried to achieve this by setting both `NumberFormat` and `Style` properties in the `Cells` that I need to modify. The code looks like this:

```
newSheet.Cells[6, 3].Value2 = 10;
newSheet.Cells[6, 3].NumberFormat = existingSheet.Cells[5, 4].NumberFormat;
newSheet.Cells[6, 3].Style = existingSheet.Cells[5, 4].Style;
```

From what I can see, the `NumberFormat` is OK now (I have set correctly the date, percent, and other number formats by doing this). But the background color, font, font color stuff do not get changed as desired. So how should I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel) and [PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel) methods.

1. `Copy` all the content of the *source* cell. Source cell has the expected formats. In your code it is the cell `Cells[5 ,4]`
2. `PasteSpecial` only the formats to the *target* cell. In your code it is the cell `Cells[6, 3]`

Example:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range source = existingSheet.Cells[5, 4];
source.Copy(); // Copy everything from the source cell to the clipboard

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range target = newSheet.Cells[6, 3];
target.Value = 456; // Write value to the target cell and ...
target.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats); // Paste only formats from the source cell
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for!